# повторный вызов скрипта до выполнения условия на стороннем сайте

Tags: php, парсер, cron

Подскажите, пожалуйста, как решить такую задачу. Нужно настроить парсинг данных с сайта-источника по расписанию (каждые 2 часа с 9 до 19 мск). Но проблема в том, что обновления на стороннем сайте-источнике выкладываются с точностью +- 15 минут от нормативного.

То есть, если я по расписанию в 11-00 запускаю скрипт, проверяющий наличие обновления и запускающий парсер, а обновления на стороннем сайте еще нет, **мне нужно каким-то образом запускать скрипт проверки снова и снова каждые 5 минут ДО ТЕХ ПОР, ПОКА не будет обновления.**

В общем, скрипт, проверяющий наличие обновлений я написала. Скрипт парсер тоже.

Но не понимаю, как мне реализовать повторный запуск скрипта проверки в случае, если на момент его работы обновления на стороннем сайте еще нет.

Буду очень благодарна за помощь.

Comment: а свой скрипт вы как по расписанию запускаете? Кроном?

Comment: Планирую использовать Cron. Но пока еще не настраивала. Хотела сначала с пхп разобраться. Я ж новичок, боюсь запутаться, если все сразу.

Comment: Запускаете кроном отдельный срипт, который отвечает за урпавление всей этой вашей системой. Скрипт проверяет, есть ли обновления и нет ли метки (о ней будет ниже). Если есть обновления и нет метки, то работает дальше. Если нет обновлений, то не делает ничего. Если обновления были и обновление прошло успешно, то вы записываете в какой-нибудь текстовый файл метку (дату, например), что обновление сегодня было проведено успешно - ставите метку. Кроном запускаете скрипт хоть каждую минуту.

Comment: Я так и сделала. У меня оставался только один вопрос (заданный выше). Я хочу остановить запуск скрипта Кроном каждые 5 минут после того,как обновление обнаружено и получено. И запускать Кроном тот же скрипт не раньше, чем через 2 часа (ко времени следующего обновления). Это возможно?

Comment: а зачем? скрипт ведь не будет по факту запускаться, если у вас стоит метка о том, что сегодня всё успешно отработало. Но если хотите возиться с созданием задач крона из php, то вот - https://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/managing-cron-jobs-with-php--net-19428

Comment: Прочитаю про метки, о которых Вы говорите. Я сначала подумала, что это то, что у меня реализовано как запись last-modified в отдельный файл при получении обновления и сравнение с уже записанным с предыдущего обновления.   А Вы, видимо, говорите о каких-то других метках

Comment: Эти метки cron устанавливает?

Comment: нет) это всё что угодно, что вы придумаете. Чтобы понять, что сегодня вы уже успешно отработали. Вы запускаете файл кроном. Если нет вашего какого-то знака (метки) и есть обновления, то вы работаете.

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/87733/discussion-between--and-n-osennij).